# When opening a file in append mode, how can I reposition the file pointer?

Tags: c, fopen

I am trying to insert some data into the middle of a file. I have opened the file in append mode as:

```
file = fopen(msg->header.filename, "ab");
```

I then tried a seek to the desired offset in the file as so:

```
fseek(file, msg->header.offset, SEEK_SET);
```

However, when I then try an fwrite as so:

```
int bytesWritten = fwrite(msg->message, 1, msg->header.length, file);
```

All the data is written to the end of the file instead of in the middle of the file.

Is this because I am using append mode? I would open in write mode, but I need to keep the existing contents in the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the specification of ANSI C function fopen for "a" (APPEND) mode:
**All** write operations take place at the end of the file.
Your fseek will ignored.

Comment: Ahh, I thought it meant that the cursor would just start at the end. Didn't realize it would resist moving.

Comment: Yes. If you want to just start at the end, you need to open it in update (`rb+`) mode and call `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);`.