# Inserting text in a file instead of overwriting in c

Tags: c, file, insert

How can I insert characters in a file using C instead of overwriting? I also want to write in start of file and end of a file. I tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037215/when-opening-a-file-in-append-mode-how-can-i-reposition-the-file-pointer) but it didn't work out (I can re-position but I cannot insert. The text is overwritten)

I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
fword = fopen("wrote.txt", "rb+");
fseek(fword, 0, SEEK_SET);
fscanf(fword, "%c", &l);
```

Comment: There is no way to insert text into a file afaik. You can overwrite existing text or append at the end of the file. To insert things, read the file to memory, do your alterations there and then write everything back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add text at the end, you can open the file with `"a"` mode (check the [fopen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) manual). It will write your text to end.

To add text in other positions, you have to read everything after that to memory, write what you want and then write the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Files are abstractions of byte streams, there is no such concept as insert in a byte stream, you can seek into certain place and write data there. The bytes you wrote will lay in the file as an array of bytes, if the writing exceeds the current file size, the file will be extended.