# fseek/fsetpos no effect when opening an existing binary file in writing mode (win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, fopen, fseek

I'm trying to write data in an existing binary file at a specific position using fseek. I'm using fopen with "ab" for file access mode.

According to the documentation, it says that write operations with the "a" mode will occur at the end of the file even after seeking to another position. fseek works fine with "wb" or "w+b" but they truncate the file.

```
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "a+b");
long long offset = 10;
_fseeki64(file, offset, SEEK_SET); //fsetpos(file, &offset);
long value = 3452;
fwrite((char*)&value, 1, sizeof(long), file);
fclose(file);
```

The value was written at the end of the file instead of offset 10.

What would be the correct file mode string to be able to modify the file at any position without truncating it?

Comment: You need to open it in update mode with `"r+b"`. See the description for [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037215/when-opening-a-file-in-append-mode-how-can-i-reposition-the-file-pointer).

Comment: Looks like i misread the description about r+, thinking it was for reading only. Works, thank you very much!

Comment: It should be `fwrite((char*)&value, sizeof(long), 1, file)`. If it were a string, then you write `fwrite(str, 1, strlen(str), file)`

Comment: I wonder why there is no `fopen` mode string equivalent of  `_open(filename, _O_RDWR | _O_CREAT | _O_BINARY, _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);`?